# Zeta functions versus Cramer's conjecture

Tags: analytic-number-theory

A mathematics professor today asked me if Cramer's conjecture on prime gaps has anything to do with Riemann Zeta function. I did not know but my guess was somehow Cramer's conjecture captures local properties while zeta functions tell global picture (from answer in here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1087381/cramer-and-riemann-conjecture-implication). Is there a connection between Cramer's conjecture-zeta functions? Cramer proved a weak gap assuming Riemann Hypothesis. Is there any other information from zeta function that can be used to address prime gaps at all (apart from information needed for GRH)?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1087381/cramer-and-riemann-conjecture-implication

Comment: thats a different question. This is particularly about zeta functions (not explicitly about GRH).

Comment: Doesn't your second last sentence answer your last question?

Comment: no.... is there any other information from zeta function that can be used to address primes gaps at all (apart from information needed for GRH, which in a sense is essentially Cramer's actual gap result because it assumes GRH)?

Comment: Well, I think it did answer your last question, until you edited it.

Comment: English is not my first language. My intention was above though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It was shown [by Heath-Brown](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=667711) that a suitable form of the pair correlation conjecture of Montgomery, in conjunction with RH, could improve Cramer's bound $p_{n+1}-p_n \ll p_n^{1/2} \log p_n$ slightly to $p_{n+1}-p_n \ll p_n^{1/2} \log^{1/2} p_n$.  This appears to be close to the limit of what one can do purely from local information on the zeta function.  Of course, thanks to the explicit formula, one could in principle extract more precise information on $p_{n+1}-p_n$ in terms of global information about zeta (e.g. involving cancellation between terms from distant zeroes) but nobody expects that such information could be at all accessible from any of our known methods, other than through the circular device of somehow first establishing bounds on $p_{n+1}-p_n$ by other, non-zeta function-based, methods, and then transforming this to an assertion about the zeta function.

Local information on zeta, such as RH or pair correlation, is more effective when dealing with averaged prime gaps, such as the second moment of $p_{n+1}-p_n$, for instance under the same hypotheses as before, Heath-Brown was able to show that $(p_{n+1}-p_n)^2$ was bounded by $O(\log^3 p_n)$ on the average.

Comment: A related question in which a possibility of a certain mutual exclusivity of GRH versus CC is given in answer http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1177623/consequences-if-cramers-conjecture-fails

Comment: The link https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1177623/consequences-if-cramers-conjecture-fails/1177649 contains Planat's paper and it provides a simultaneous condition for truth of RH and falsity of Cramer and has no citations and perhaps not many have opined on the importance of the paper (if any).